# How come my question is opinion based and this question is on topic?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Biology Stack Exchange post: [Is there any biological reason why so many men find breasts sexually attractive?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/98556/is-there-any-biological-reason-why-so-many-men-find-breasts-sexually-attractive)

If you see, this question is accepted on this network: [Why are (some) male humans sexually attracted to the breasts of female humans?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/84584/why-are-some-male-humans-sexually-attracted-to-the-breasts-of-female-humans)

And my question is almost same. Moreover, I've provided some additional details what I read about.

Now I've many reasons why my question is opinion-based, but it makes me doubt seeing the other question.

When I don't add detail, people say you didn't do research. When I did, it is still opinion based given the fact an almost similar question is already asked by someone.

Also, I've tried to edit it after multiple feedbacks in such a way that it remains specific and not opinion based.

Further, someone told me "why" questions are sometimes hard to answer. This question also starts with a proper why.

So I really don't understand. Why is it so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question you link to is nearly 2 years old and this site's conventions change over time.

I can't be positive, but my feeling is that the linked question would be closed swiftly when it would be posted now, mainly because it is underresearched (i.e., it's a one-liner, aka a 'homework' question). However, the question is somewhat less opinion-based as yours, as it's asking for evolutionary underpinnings. But because of the little background research it's quite pob imo.

For what it's worth, the linked question was apparently quite poorly received and it additionally received 2 close votes back then - also with the pob close-vote reason (primarily opinion based). The close votes have aged away since as the critical 5-vote threshold hasn't been reached.

Comment: What if I also change my words to evolutionary?

Comment: I've updated my question accordingly.

Comment: And I didn't understand the word "pob". Could you please tell meaning of it? I Googled but found no luck.

Comment: @vivek - pob is explained in the answer. 'Evolutionary' is not the magic word that magically makes every question ontopic. On the contrary in fact, questions on evolution can be met with quite some criticism. The magic word is pob. Adding a word here or there won't change that.

Comment: but you said the other question was less opinion based because it focused on evolution?

Comment: @vivek - repeat - 'Evolutionary' is not the magic word that magically makes every question ontopic. On the contrary in fact, questions on evolution can be met with quite some criticism. The magic word is pob. Adding a word here or there won't change that.

Comment: I understand it perfectly :D, but I just wanted to know how the other question was less opinion based when they focused on evolution and same is not true for my question when I focused on evolution?

Comment: @vivek stop focusing on minutiae. The old question received 4 downvotes and 2 close votes - that's not exactly "being accepted on this network." We have a chronically difficult time here closing inappropriate questions, as there often aren't enough engaged users with close vote privileges voting to close garbage questions. More recently the mods have been more involved in closing questions like this when it's clear there's community consensus, but this old question apparently missed that scrutiny. I would hope that it gets closed now.

Comment: @MattDMo lol it's closed now. Makes sense to me now :D